# How can I generate a list of function calls in the sort order of values of the calls?

Tags: sorting

My problem is that I have a defined function, say, `foo`, and I am using the built in `Sort` function to order a sequence of calls

```
foo[x1], food[x2], ..., foo[xn]
```

from lowest value to greatest.

However,

```
Sort[{foo[x1], foo[x2]}, ..., foo[xn]]
```

outputs the numerical evaluation of foo[xi]

so that (for example) I get an output like

> ```
>  {1.1, 3.9 ,..., 9.7}
> ```

Assuming `foo[x11]` evaluates to the lowest, `foo[x3]` the second lowest and `foo[x108]` the greatest numerical value, I want the output to be

> ```
> {foo[x11], foo[x3], ..., foo[x108]}
> ```

I also tried

```
 HoldForm[Sort[{foo[x1], foo[x2]},...,foo[xn]]]
```

and using `HoldForm` on the individual elements given to `Sort`, but neither worked.

Perhaps there is a simpler way of doing what I want to do (list me the order of foo[xi] from lowest value to greatest). Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you can use `SortBy`: `SortBy[{1.1, 3.9, ..}, foo]`

Comment: A concrete example is needed here. Otherwise people have to guess what is wanted.

Answer (score 2):

```
foo[x_] = x;

SeedRandom[0]

list = (Inactive[foo] /@ RandomInteger[{100}, 5])
```

[image]

```
SortBy[list, Activate]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
foo = #^2&;
list = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 5]
Inactive[foo] /@ SortBy[list, foo]
```

[image]

```
Defer[foo] /@ SortBy[list, foo]
```

> {foo[0.02234],foo[0.027387],foo[0.070565],foo[0.20430],foo[-0.91121]}